# javascript/html/php: Is it possible to insert a value into a form with Ajax?

Tags: ajax, forms

I have a form where users enter some text manually.  Then I'd like to let the users choose a tag from a database through AJAX, not unlike how tag suggestions appear in the SO question form.  While the div where the ajax call places the tag is inside the form, it does not seem to register and the tag is not picked up by the form.  Am I missing something in my code, is this impossible or, if impossible there a better way to do this?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is code:

html

```
<form method="post" action="enterdata.php">
<input type="text" name="text">Enter text here.
<div id="inserttags"></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getTags()";>Get tags</a>
<form type="button" name="submit" value="Enter Text and Tag">
</form>
```

javascript

```
getTags() { 
various Ajax goes here, then
//following line inserts value into div of html
    document.getElementById("inserttags").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
// a bit more ajax, then following pulls tag from db 
xmlhttp.open("GET","findtags.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
} //end function
```

php

```
//gettags.php
//first pull tag from db.  Then:
echo 'input type="text" name="tag" value= "html">Enter tag';
//above output gets inserted in div and is visible on page.
```

Though the above output is visible on page, the form does not seem to pick it up when you click "Enter Text and Tag" to submit the form.

Comment: so u r basically inserting an input tag inside a div tag, correct?

Comment: yes  is that allowed?  Question really is, is html inserted on client side through javascript really there and part of the html for purposes of submitting a form.

Comment: yes, you are doing that right via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and much pondering, I don't think you can do what I wanted to do...use the native html form to capture the javascript output even with the div inside the form.  Instead, the way to do this is to capture the text field using javascript and then place it inside a form within the ajax outputted to the browser as a hidden value along with the tags. Then the user submits the form with both the text and tag, not using the original html but rather a button or link in the ajax output.  If anyone knows a better way, I stand corrected, but this way will work, and the html form does not seem to recognize the values in the div inserted by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

the input tag looks incomplete. try `<input type="text" name="tag" value= "html" />Enter tag`. Also, the click event is attached to the link tag `Get tags`, so you would need to click that link to make the ajax function call.

Edit:

```
 $('#inserttags').append(xmlhttp.responseText));
```

Comment: yes that is the idea.  You click and the html with the tag appears via the ajax.  That is working.  Problem is when you submit form, that new html does not seem to be inside the form.  I don't know of a good way to view the source after an ajax call.

Comment: that's coz the form tag is not enclosing the div tag. whatever tags/html you want to submit, that form tag needs to enclose all those tags, does that make sense?

Comment: I suppose you meant this tag to be a button? `<form type="submit" value="Enter Text and Tag">` ...like `<button type="submit" value="Enter Text and Tag" \>` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I left out button.  I think the div tag is within the form tag--although it is empty prior to the ajax call which fills it.  Now corrected in question.

Comment: Also, close the `form` tag at the end, if you haven't and try that. You try `append()` instead of `innerHTML` as in http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: I upvoted it but am still fiddling to try to get it to work.  There may be a typo on my end somewhere

Comment: I am not using jquery. Could it be that you cannot do what I'm trying to do, ie once the original html is loaded, the rewritten code in the div by way of ajax is not accessible to the html form?